# Почему `(false == []) === true`?

Tags: javascript

Готовлюсь к собесу. И хочу понять почему

`(false == []) === true`, и в тоже время

`(false == Boolean([])) === false`.

Как такое явление можно объяснить?

Я понимаю, что в первом случае для массива будет вызван `ToPrimitive()`,
а затем вроде должен отработать `valueOf()`.
Возможно я не прав, но похоже, что этот метод вернет значение `length`, который равен 0, что в свою очередь является falsy значением, так что-ли?

Comment: нет не так. ToPrimitive никак с length не работает

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, за полезное замечание.

Comment: Интересно, а кто будет на собесе задавать такую чушь? В реалиях TypeScript этот код неуместен, поэтому и понять не могу, кому нужно заниматься такой ерундой

Comment: @MoloF, а причем тут TypsScript если вопрос про javascript? Кроме того, TypeScript не панацея и в нем, приведение типов работает точно так же

Comment: @Grundy не думаю что компания может позволить себе писать на голом JS когда без строгой типизации ни один проект не сможет поддерживаться несколькими разработчиками. Я не знаю в каких случаях может пригодится подобное сравнение, в реалиях тайпскрипта данная запись невозможна, последние пару лет забыл про `==`, всегда обходился `===`.

Comment: @MoloF, проекты без строгой типизации спокойно поддерживаются несколькими разработчиками ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ в реалиях тайпскрипта данная запись вполне возможна. Если кто-то не использует возможности языка - не значит что их никто не использует :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Массив при нестрогом сравнении с примитивом конвертируется в пустую строку, поэтому при дальнейшем нестрогом сравнении с `false` и получается совпедение. Но если вы явно преобразуете объект в булево значние, возвращается `true`, поэтому второй результат такой.

См. подробности в https://javascript.info/array#don-t-compare-arrays-with

Comment: Вообще, если прям совсем совсем по спецификации, то сначала `false` конвертируется в number, потом массив в строку, потом в number и в итоге два числа сравниваются